# Add vertical line to pandas df.plot of timeseries

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, datetime, plot, time-series

I have a time series plot and I would like to add a vertical line to it at `event time`. If I use this code:

```
event_time = pd.to_datetime('10/12/2016 06:21:00')
ax = df_stats_t.plot(x = 't', y='t_TI_var_pwr', linestyle='none',...
color = 'black', marker = 'o')
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax1.axvline(event_time, color='red', linestyle='-')
df_stats_t.plot(x='t',y='t_TI_var_ws',ax=ax1, linestyle='none', ...
color = 'green', marker = 'o')
```

It takes a subset of the time series starting at `event_time` and doesn't produce a vertical line.

[image]

If I move `ax1.axvline(event_time, color='red', linestyle='-')` to the bottom, I get the plot I want but the vertical line is still missing.

```
    event_time = pd.to_datetime('10/12/2016 06:21:00')
    ax = df_stats_t.plot(x = 't', y='t_TI_var_pwr', linestyle='none',... 
    color = 'black', marker = 'o')
    ax1 = ax.twinx()
    df_stats_t.plot(x='t',y='t_TI_var_ws',ax=ax1, linestyle='none',... 
    color = 'green', marker = 'o')
    ax1.axvline(event_time, color='red', linestyle='-')
```

[image]

How can I get the vertical line to discplay at x = event_time for all y values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works with `plt`

```
ax = df_stats_t.plot(x = 't', y='t_TI_var_pwr', linestyle='none', color = 'black', marker = 'o')
ax1 = ax.twinx()
df_stats_t.plot(x='t',y='t_TI_var_ws',ax=ax1, linestyle='none', color = 'green', marker = 'o')
plt.axvline(event_time, color='red', linestyle='-')
```